# How to change iSeries Admin2 JAVA_HOME environmental variable

Tags: ibm-midrange, java-home, iseries-navigator

I'm running V7R2, I have JDK80 as well as JDK71 installed.
My PTF level are up to date (that's why i have issues in the first place).

My ADMIN2 instance is choosing to use JAVA 1.7, which is giving some problems to Navigator (not all data is displayed).
As far as I know Navigator should work fine with JAVA 1.8.

I set my JAVA_HOME environment variable with value (both WRKENVVAR and WRKENVVAR LEVEL(*SYS))

```
/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk80/64bit
```

But ADMIN2 instance is showing me that it's using:

```
/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk71/64bit
```

Same observation when browsing messages.log (on liberty)

DO you guys know how to force ADMIN2 to use different JAVA?

Answer (score 2):

OK, found the issue.

I was missing 5770JV1 option 17:

- installed it
- installed latest related PTF
- IPL

it's working fine now.